# Can I use a free cloud database on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, web-hosting

I built a simple **Web Application** using **GWT** and deployed it to **Google App Engine** Now I want to build my database and integrate it to my website I searched for it all what I found is **Google Cloud SQL**
and I have to pay for it

any free solution.I just want to build simple project for 1 user use

*Tip: database using **MYSQL**

Comment: The datastore is free up to a certain amount of quota, so if you don't *need* SQL, this is a fine solution. Using the tools provided, you can create your own models and make sure they adhere to some schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one way to have a free solution:

1. You will need to have to learn Google App Engine Datastore. This is another alternative to using a database such as MySQL.

Comment: You can't use JDBC on App Engine because you can't open sockets directly. The closest thing you can find is [Google Secure Data Connector](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/), which works over HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an introductory free trial for Google Cloud SQL.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing